# Create a new dataframe by applying function to columns of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

I try to learn more about the apply method in python and asking myself how to write the following code using apply:

I have a dataframe df like the following:

```
  A B C D E points
0 0 0 0 1 43 94
1 0 0 1 1 55 62
2 1 1 0 1 21 84
3 1 0 1 0 13 20
```

Furthermore I have a function like the following, which does its job:

```
def f1(df):
  df_means = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Mean_Points'])
  for columnname in df.columns:
    if len(df[df[columnname] == 1]) > 1:
      df_means.loc[columnname] = [df[df[columnname] == 1]['points'].mean()]
  return df_means
```

So the output of f1 is

```
  'Mean_Points'
A      52
C      41
D      80
```

and that's totally fine.
But I am wondering if there is a possibility (I am sure there is) to obtain the same result with the apply method. 
I tried:

```
df_means = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Mean_Points'])
cols = [col for col in df.columns if len(df[df[col] == 1]) > 1]
df_means.loc[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: df[df[x] == 1]['points'].mean(), axis = 1)
```

or similar:

```
df_means = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Mean_Points'])
df.columns.apply(lambda x: df_means.loc[x] = [df[df[x] == 1]['points'].mean()] if len(df[df[x] == 1]) > 1 else None)
```

and 2,3 other things, but nothing worked...
I hope somebody can help me here?!

Comment: Explain the logic behind your function.

Comment: What is going on with column `E`?

Comment: The function checks for every column in df, if a '1' appears multiple times in that column. If that is the case it creates a new row in df_means with the columnname as index and the mean value of df['points'] where the '1's appear in the column of df as column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`pd.DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html)

```
#                      filters s to be just those
#                      things greater than 1
#                      v
s = df.eq(1).sum().loc[lambda x: x > 1]
df.loc[:, s.index].T.dot(df.points).div(s)

A    52.0
C    41.0
D    80.0
dtype: float64
```

---

#### One liner approach

This removes the chaff but probably does more calculations than necessary.

```
df.T.dot(df.points).div(df.sum())[df.eq(1).sum().gt(1)]

A    52.0
C    41.0
D    80.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Howdy pi!  Always nice to see your analytical mathematical approaches. +1

Comment: o/ @ScottBoston (-:

Comment: Yes, this is cleaner than mine with all the garbage multiplications you then drop :D

Answer (score 3):

In general, you should try to see if you can avoid using `.apply(axis=1)`.

In this case, you can get by with `DataFrame.mulitply()`, replacing `0` with `np.NaN` so it doesn't count toward the average.

```
import numpy as np

s = df.replace(0, np.NaN).multiply(df.points, axis=0).mean()
#A           52.0
#B           84.0
#C           41.0
#D           80.0
#E         2369.0
#points    5034.0
#dtype: float64
```

Now we'll add your condition to only consider columns with multiple instances of `1`, and subset to those with `.reindex`

```
m = df.eq(1).sum().gt(1)
s = s.reindex(m[m].index)
```

#### Output `s`:

```
A      52.0
C      41.0
D      80.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, not purely *pandas* as others have shown.

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

def consolidate(series):
    cond = series > 0
    points = df.loc[cond, 'points']
    if len(points) > 1:
        return series.name, points.mean()
    else:
        return series.name, np.nan

df1 = pd.DataFrame([consolidate(df[col]) for col in cols], columns=['name', 'mean_points'])


print(df1)


  name  mean_points
0    A         52.0
1    B          NaN
2    C         41.0
3    D         80.0
```

If no `NaN` needed then

```
df1.dropna()

  name  mean_points
0    A         52.0
2    C         41.0
3    D         80.0
```

And using `apply`

```
df[cols].apply(consolidate,result_type='expand')
        .T.dropna()
        .reset_index()
        .drop('index', axis=1)

0  A  52
1  C  41
2  D  80
```